# Get only current month's duration data from it range included over two months

Tags: php, sql, laravel

If sample data as below, how can I make implement that to calculate the data only matched with current month as `June` by Laravel or PHP code?

`ID     user_name         created_at          deleted_at             duration`

```
1      John           2018-05-20 00:00:00    2018-06-08 00:00:00    18000
1      John           2018-06-01 00:00:00    2018-06-08 00:00:00    8000
1      John           2018-06-01 00:00:00    2018-07-04 00:00:00    34000 
2      Michael        2018-06-05 00:00:00    2018-06-20 00:00:00    15000
```

`*              User('John')'s total duration of this Month(June) is xxxxx`

Originally, I used the below code to sort the current month's data.

```
$workings = DB::table('workings')
                ->where('user_name', $user_name)
                ->whereMonth('created_at', date('m'))
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
                ->paginate(22);
```

But below code make more accuracy sorting.

```
$workings = DB::table('workings')
                ->where('user_name', $user_name)
                ->whereMonth('created_at', date('m'))
                ->orwhere(function ($query) use($user_name) {
                    $query->where('user_name', $user_name)
                    ->whereMonth('deleted_at', date('m'));
                    })
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
                ->orderBy('deleted_at', 'asc')
                ->paginate(22);
```

Nevertheless I think also this code not correcting only current month's duration data, because some record included over current month's duration as `May` and `July` in above sample data.

So I need any other solution to calculate current month's data only.

How can I get the sum of the duration values of a current month from data that contains two months?

Comment: try `->whereDate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by myself as below, but I wrote this code into Laravel View file instead of Controller.

Could you tell me how to reduce code length or advice?

```
...
$sum_duration = 0; 
foreach($workings as $working){

   $startOfMonth = strtotime(Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfMonth());
   $endOfMonth = strtotime(Carbon\Carbon::now()->endOfMonth());

   $created_at = strtotime($working->created_at);
   $deleted_at = strtotime($working->deleted_at);

   $duration = $deleted_at - $created_at;

   if( $startOfMonth > $created_at )
   {
      $working->job_times = 27000; //user's one day work time.
      $beforeMonth = $startOfMonth - $created_at;
      $index = floor($beforeMonth / 86400);
      $duration_beforeMonth = $index * $working->job_times;

      $duration = $working->duration - $duration_beforeMonth + $working->job_times;
      echo $duration;
   }


   elseif( $endOfMonth < $deleted_at )
   {
      $afterMonth = $deleted_at - $endOfMonth;
      $index = floor($afterMonth / 86400);
      $afterMonth = $index * $working->job_times;

      $duration = $working->duration - $afterMonth;
      echo $duration;
   }

   elseif($startOfMonth <= $created_at && $endOfMonth >= $deleted_at)
   {
      $duration = $working->duration;
      $duration);
   }

 $sum_duration += $duration;
}

echo $sum_duration;

...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `whereBetween` https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries

```
$startOfMonth = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth();
$endOfMonth = Carbon::now()->endOfMonth();

$workings = DB::table('workings')
                ->where('user_name', $user_name)
                ->whereBetween('created_at', [$startOfMonth, $endOfMonth])
                ->whereBetween('deleted_at', [$startOfMonth, $endOfMonth])
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
                ->get();
```

--

Also, you can use the `->sum()` aggregate to sum up the `duration` column for you

Just replace `->get()` with `->sum('duration')`

Comment: In addition, How can I get the sum of the duration values of a given month from data that contains two months? thank you to your advice, :)

Comment: @Magnetic i'm not sure what you mean, can you please edit your question and add an explanation/example, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `whereBetween`

```
$workings = DB::table('workings')
    ->where('user_name', $user_name)
    ->whereBetween($created_at, $deleted_at)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
    ->get();
```

Source: [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries)

You can use the included Carbon library to calculate the difference in a human readable format.

For example, you could create Carbon objects from the timestamps:

`$timeStamp1 = Carbon::createFromTimestampUTC($timeStamp1);`
`$timeStamp2 = Carbon::createFromTimestampUTC($timeStamp2);`

then use the carbon functions to output it in whatever format you wish

`$timeStamp1->diffInHours($timeStamp2);`

Answer (score 0):

The Laravel query builder has a [`whereMonth`](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereMonth) function that be used to filter on the month of a date.

So you can use the following query to get all results where `created_at` is in june:

```
DB::table('workings')
    ->where('user_name', $user_name)
    ->whereMonth('created_at', 6)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: How can I get the sum of the duration values of a given month from data that contains two months?